# Investor badge and Investing badge

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

At some point, we will have both the [Investor](https://money.stackexchange.com/badges/29/investor) badge (a general badge), and the [investing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/investing) badge (a tag badge).  The investing badge doesn't exist yet, but it's third most popular tag, with 3 users over 50 upvotes.

I see it as a amusing, and don't see any problems, given that badges don't play a central role in the site.

Answer (score 1):

More amusing than that is the fact that we will have [united-states](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) badges and [canada](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada) badges.